# How do you keep hover in effect for 3 seconds after you stop hovering over it in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

What this code does is when you hover over an item in a list, it changes to red, and displays another list below.  If you are no longer hovering over any elements, the goal is to have the latest thing you hovered over stay there for 3 seconds before it's cleared.

```
$('#stockList li').hover(
            function () {
                    $(this).css({ color: 'red' }); //mouseover
                    if ($(this).text() == symbol) {

                        $('#stockInfo').append('<div><ol><li>' + "Company = " + company + '</li><br/><li>' + "Market = " + market + '</li><br/><li>' + "Sector = " + sector + '</li><br/><li>' + "Price = " + price + '</li><br/><li>' + "Year Range = " + low + " " + high + '</li><br/><li>' + "Dividend = " + amount + " " + yieldx + " " + frequency + '</li></ol><br/></div>');
                    }
                },

            function () {
                $(this).css({ color: 'navy' }); // mouseout
                $('#stockInfo').empty();
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `delay` to it:

```
$(this).delay(3000).css({ color: 'navy' }); // mouseout
$('#stockInfo').empty();
```

Remember that javascript time works with miliseconds, so 3 seconds is 3000 miliseconds in javascript.

See the jQuery docs on delay [here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Answer (score 0):

Hover effect remains their until you take mouse cursor off the element

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/ceZ7X/2/)

You can do something like this :

```
var timeout;
    $('#stockList li').hover(
           function () {
              clearTimeout(timeout);// this will take care if user re-hover over the element
              $(this).css({ color: 'red' }); //mouseover
                  if ($(this).text() == symbol) {        
                     $('#stockInfo').append('<div><ol><li>' + "Company = " + company + '</li><br/><li>' + "Market = " + market + '</li><br/><li>' + "Sector = " + sector + '</li><br/><li>' + "Price = " + price + '</li><br/><li>' + "Year Range = " + low + " " + high + '</li><br/><li>' + "Dividend = " + amount + " " + yieldx + " " + frequency + '</li></ol><br/></div>');
                        }
                    },

                function () {
               timeout=  setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#stockList li').css({ color: 'navy' }); // mouseout
                    $('#stockInfo').empty();
                  },3000);
                }
            );
```

Comment: why do you declare `timeout` in the outer scope?

Comment: just to make sure that it can be used in both function's

Comment: The problem I'm getting with that is it just keeps displaying new lists, they are never disappearing.

Comment: Okay, so I only want it to do it when it's not hovering over any of the items in the list.  It keeps making new lists depending on what you're hovering over, and then after 3 seconds once your not hovering over anything it disappears.

Comment: Also the color isn't going back to navy in the list

Comment: That does work now, awesome.  The only thing is I only want this to be in effect when it's not hovering over anything.  Is that a possibility?  When you hover over something it makes a list.  And what it's doing it it makes more and more lists until you move off of it completely.

Comment: I can't because it's pulling from an xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#stockList li').hover(
            function () {
                    $(this).css({ color: 'red' }); //mouseover
                    if ($(this).text() == symbol) {

                        $('#stockInfo').append('<div><ol><li>' + "Company = " + company + '</li><br/><li>' + "Market = " + market + '</li><br/><li>' + "Sector = " + sector + '</li><br/><li>' + "Price = " + price + '</li><br/><li>' + "Year Range = " + low + " " + high + '</li><br/><li>' + "Dividend = " + amount + " " + yieldx + " " + frequency + '</li></ol><br/></div>');
                    }
                },

            function () {
                setTimeOut(function(){
                    $(this).css({ color: 'navy' }); // mouseout
                    $('#stockInfo').children('div').remove();
                },3000); // Disappear after 3000 ms or 3 seconds
            }
);
```

Comment: The problem I'm getting with that is it just keeps displaying new lists, they are never disappearing.

Comment: updated my answer.. use remove method to remove the appended part

Comment: It's still not removing the lists.

Comment: try with $('#stockInfo').children().remove();

Comment: This means your setTimeOut is not getting fired.. Try with setInterval.. I'll update my answer in a minute..

Comment: `setInterval` will execute this every 3 second, You are in an infinite Loop.